# Tizen. net CircleStepper, is there any way to prevent/control wrap around

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, xamarin.tizen

Is it possible to control the wrap around of the Tizen CircleStepper?

I use the following to create a CircleStepper:

```
var circleStepper = new CircleStepper
            {
                Title = "stepper",
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                Increment = 1,
                LabelFormat = "%1.1f",
                Maximum = 100.0,
                Minimum = 0.0,
                Value = 50,
            };
```

But I cannot find any control of the wraparound function and it is always possible to pull/push control to and from max <> min values as shown here:

[image]

What I would like to do is prevent this wraparound behavior.
Advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature requested and a [pull request](https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.CircularUI/pull/224) was created:

There is now an `IsWrapEnabled` Property in CircleStepper

Available in 1.5.0 Preview 1

Answer (score 0):

When I have test with your snippet code, displaying is different your screenshot.
I have tested tizen 4.0/5.0 emulator. Title and value(50.0) is displayed but there were no max and min value in screen. and CircleStpper doesn't have circle scroll bar(blue circle bar in your screen shot). please refer to [circlestepper guide](https://samsung.github.io/Tizen.CircularUI/guide/CircleStepper.html)

There will be helpful if you add emulator version or provide your code more. 
you can raise issue in https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.CircularUI/issues with detail information.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJjJB.png)

Comment: I intentionally drag the stepper down to reveal that I could not prevent the wrap around from min to max value.  Depending on the size you create the stepper, you may be able to reveal more than 1 value at a time.  So if your stepper is default size, then you would be able to only display one value if you do not drag it.
For example if you add initialize value, HeightRequest = 350,  then you can see 3 values at a time in the stepper.

Regarding the Circle scroll bar, it's just something i added, but of course has nothing to do with the stepper.  sorry i should have removed it for clarity

Comment: Regarding wrap around issue, can you confirm it is or is not possible to prevent stepper wrap around from min <> max values?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I added feature request here:
https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.CircularUI/issues/223